# KineticJS HTML5 Canvas Harmonic Oscillator

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs, physics

I want to make [similar thing](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-harmonic-oscillator/) using KineticS. But got only such thing - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CptLd. Can you help me, please?

Comment: You can put this example's drawing code into a Kinetic.Shape:  http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-shape-tutorial/  Then you can use a Kinetic.Animation to animate the oscillation: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-animation-tutorial/

Comment: @markE, can you give me an example?

Comment: Check out the Kinetic.Shape.  It gives you a canvas context to draw with so you can put the drawing code from the example into the Shape's sceneFunc.  Give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

```
var anim = new Kinetic.Animation(function(frame) {
  var scale = Math.abs(0.5 * (Math.sin(2* Math.PI * frame.time / 3000) + 1.5));
  weight.setY(200 * scale + 40);
  spline.scale({y:scale});
}, layer);
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nraLo